# Unable To Remove DPM Agent

Tags: windows-server-2003, scdpm

I have installed the DPM 2010 Agent on a Windows Server 2003 that act as a Secondary AD. Since it was demoted, I'm unable to get DPM to work.

According to this :
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff399208.aspx

I need to remove the current DPM agent and reinstall it again.

Problem :

The DPM doesn't show up on Add/Remove.
I can't find the uninstaller or a CLI option.
The current DPM server doesn't see this agent , so remote uninstall is not an option.

How can DPM Agent be removed?

Answer (score 1):

1. Run PowerShell (The DPM management shell) as administrator.
2. In DPM 2010 PowerShell write “remove-productionserver.ps1”. Press enter
3. You will be prompted to enter the DPMServername, write your DPM server name that you are trying to remove the DPM agent from. Press Enter
4. Then write the DPM agent name that you trying to remove. Press Enter
   You will be prompted that the agent is been removed and you will see the agent is been removed from the DPM 2010 Management agents tab.

---

**On the agent:**

If it's not showing up in Add/Remove programs, try:

For a 32-bit operating system, at the command prompt type

```
Msiexec /x {07CCDE6A-1D92-2C9C-D091-9E682643ABCC}
```

For 64-bit operating system, at the command prompt type

```
Msiexec /x {72BF00D8-53E0-1539-F523-4347082BCC11}
```

PS - Writing MS with a dollar sign stopped being cool about 15 years ago.

Sources:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff629522.aspx

http://laithalmashta.blogspot.com/2011/09/cannot-remove-dpm-2010-agent-from-dpm.html

Comment: Hello Ryan. Windows Reports This App. Is Not Installed When Using The Commands Above.